# How to print output from DateTime and Diff into a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, datetime, diff

How can I send the output from this code into a new variable?

```
$var1 = new DateTime('09:43');
$var2 = new DateTime('10:55');
$interval = $var1->diff($var2);
echo $interval->format('%H%i');
```

This results in "0112"

I want to do something like this but obviously the syntax is incorrect:

```
$var1 = new DateTime('09:43');
$var2 = new DateTime('10:55');
$interval = $var1->diff($var2);
$var3 = "echo $interval->format('%H%i')";
```

Comment: What's wrong with just `$var3 = $interval->format('%H%i');`?

Comment: Good grief :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
$var3 = $interval->format('%H%i');
echo $var3 ;
```